# How to use binary cross entropy for a sequence of bits

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I want to apply binary cross entropy function for a prediction of a sequence of N length bits ( for example a sequence of 10 bits  `[1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0]` as ground truth). Model output after a softmax layer is of size `[10, 2]`. second dimension refers to `[Prob(x=0), Prob(x=1)]`. I want to calculate the `binary_crossentropy`  loss for this sequence.

So my ground truth is of size [?, 10] and my model output is of size [?, 10 , 2]. How to use `binary_crossentropy` loss in this scenario?

As for this, I get an error as 
`Error when checking target: expected model_3 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (batchsize, 10).`

When I use Prob(x=0) or  Prob(x=1)] from the softmax output, I do not get desired results. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a binary bit ground truth of shape `(None, 10)`, the model output should be of the same shape. Since each bit is independent, you should use a sigmoid activation at the output, not a softmax one, in order to use the `binary_crossentropy` loss:

```
output = Dense(10, activation="sigmoid")(layer_input)
# Alternatively you can just use an activation layer:
output = Activation("sigmoid")(layer_input)


model = Model(input, output)
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="binary_crossentropy")
```

An important detail is that the output of the model is continuous in `[0, 1]`, to get the bit predictions, you have to threshold the output of the model at 0.5 (this is how keras computes binary accuracy):

```
raw_preds = model.predict(some_inputs)
bit_preds = raw_preds > 0.5
```

If you want to keep the current model using softmax, then you have to one-hot encode the labels so they have shape `(None, 10, 2)`, and then use `categorical_crossentropy` as the loss.

Comment: By using Dense layer it adds more weights to the network right? In the model I use, the final softmax is added as a layer as the model just before it is not a neural network. Is there a way I can add just a sigmoid layer?

Comment: @toinahseh Yes but those details are not really answerable unless you include your model code.

Comment: I used a Lambda layer to add a sigmoid layer as ```output = Lambda(lambda x: keras.backend.sigmoid(x))(output)``` .  I will try training with your method. Thanks

Comment: @toinahseh You can do the same with Activation("sigmoid"), as mentioned in the updated answer